# How to detect the next open/close of a candlestick that doesn't go through a wick of another candle in PineScript?

Tags: pine-script

How to detect open/close candlesticks above and below that doesn't go through a wick of another candle? The blue lines demonstrates what I want to. Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Your real problem is to define "wick of another". Is it some bars back from the current bar? Is it the highest/lowest bar X bars back? Do you want to get back an index number of a bar whose wick the current bar has pierced through?

Answer (score 1):

You can first define number of bars from last bar that you want to check for open/close. At the last bar you can run for loop for that many bars. At each iteration of loop you can keep calculating the maxiumum high and minimum lows that occured after the selected bar. If open/close is not breaching them, then draw the line. Example below

```
//@version=5

indicator(title="Unbreached High/Low by Rohit", shorttitle="URR",overlay=true,max_lines_count=500,max_labels_count=500,max_bars_back=1500)
var maxbars = input.int(20,title="max bars")
var maxhigh=high
var minlow=low
if barstate.islast
    var openclosearray=array.new_float()
    maxhigh:=high
    minlow:=low
    for i = 1 to maxbars
        if open[i]<close[i] and open[i]<minlow
            line.new(bar_index-i,open[i],bar_index,open[i],extend=extend.right)
        if open[i]>close[i] and open[i]>maxhigh
            line.new(bar_index-i,open[i],bar_index,open[i],extend=extend.right)
        if close[i]<open[i] and close[i]<minlow
            line.new(bar_index-i,close[i],bar_index,close[i],extend=extend.right)
        if close[i]>open[i] and close[i]>maxhigh
            line.new(bar_index-i,close[i],bar_index,close[i],extend=extend.right)
        if low[i]<minlow
            minlow:=low[i]
        if high[i]>maxhigh
            maxhigh:=high[i]
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if that's exactly what you're looking for?
https://www.tradingview.com/script/cgHGBnH9-Naked-Intrabar-POC/